# Laravel: How to pass parameters in controller

Tags: laravel, function, methods, model, controller

I want to use one method in all models I tried below methods but its not working, can you guys please help me to fix this.

I created the below method testing in User model:

```
public function testing($user)
{
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($user as $users) {

        if ($users->RolePermission->isEmpty())
        {
            return view('authorize');
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($users->RolePermission as $permission)
            {
               return $arr[] = $permission->permission_id;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to use above method in HomeController but I don't know how it works:
I tried below in HomeController.
for example:

```
public function checkRights()
{
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $id = $auth->id;
    $user = User::Where('id', $id)->with('RolePermission')->get();

 //now here i want to use the method named testing

    $user = User::::with('testing('.$user.')');

   return view('authorization',compact('user'));
}
```

I tried to use the testing function with above code but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the method `testing` as static:

```
public static function testing($user)
```

Then call it like this:

```
$user = User::testing($user);
```